# Орфографія слова "Полова" (відходи зерна)

Tags: орфографія

Дуже рідко зустрічав слово "Полова" (відходи зерна), тому не знаю чи його можна вживати у множині.

Приклади:
"В цьому мішку зібрано зерно різних полов."
"Під час обмолоту утворюються великі кількості полов."

Підкажіть чи це правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зазвичай слово *поло́ва* вважають **збірним іменником**, тобто іменником, який граматично завжди має форму однини, але вживається на позначення неозначеної кількості предметів (як-от: *волосся*, *городина*, *хмиз*).

[«Словники України online» від УМІФ](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) подають лише форми однини для цього слова. 16-та версія «Генерального регіонально анотованого корпусу української мови» не містить [жодного трапляння](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac16&queryselector=word&keyword=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%7C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%7C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%7C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85&showresults=1) слова *полова* у множині («вскочили половами в кущі» і «по половах ходити не будемо» виявилися описками від «вскочили головами в кущі» і «по полонах ходити не будемо» відповідно).

Відповідно, Ваші приклади я б переформулював так:

- <s>*Під час обмолоту утворюються великі кількості полов.*</s>
  *Під час обмолоту (чи обмолочування) утворюється велика кількість полови.*
- <s>*В цьому мішку зібрано зерно різних полов.*</s>
  Тут мені не зовсім зрозуміло, що хотіли сказати. Можливо: *«У цьому мішку зібрано зерно різних сортів/видів/крупів»*?